# Delete or hide a character at the end of a line if a line break occurs with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage that ends with a series of links for credits, with each link separated by an em dash. While this works fine on large screens, in smaller windows the list wraps to two or more lines. I know I can use non-breaking spaces to keep each link together on a line, but I was wondering if there was a way to delete or hide the dashes if they occur at a word break, so that when there is a word wrap

`link1 &mdash; link2 &mdash; link3 &mdash; link4 &mdash; link5`

would display as

> link1 — link2 — link3
>
> link4 — link5

rather than

> link1 — link2 — link3 —
>
> link4 — link5

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can adjust the HTML like you want ?

Comment: if you use an absolute ::before pseudo, to generate the —; character, then it can be hidden via overflow ... what have you tried so far ?